# Setup project not installing referenced project content files

Tags: .net, setup-project

I have a Windows Service project, A, with a dependency on a class library project, B. Project B has XML files set as `Content`, `Copy if newer`. In the `bin\Debug` folder of project A, these content files are successfully copied.

**Edit (more failure):**

The `Primary output` installs fine. I cannot get the `Content Files` to install.

**Edit (win):**

I had it all wrong, I have `Primary Output` from Project A and added a custom action to install it because it's the service exe. `Content files` from Project B simply have to be included in the setup project... not "installed" as a custom action.

Comment: I have this same problem in Visual Studio 2010, and have also gotten it to work by adding each content file of the dependent project to the setup project. I find it surprising that this should be the desired behavior, and even more surprising that there doesn't seem to be any way to change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think so, yes. When I use the setup project, I have to explicitly reference Project A's Primary output and content files, as well as all of Project B's DLL files.