# Windows service setup project doesn't copy referenced dlls

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, windows-installer, installation

I've just built a windows service and it runs like a dream in debug/release on my dev machine. I've created a setup project following steps in walkthroughs such as [this blog post](http://blog.tallan.com/2009/06/01/creating-a-project-installer-for-a-windows-service/), [this msdn walkthrough](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169), and [this generous answer to a rather lazy SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803).

My project installs fine on a target machine, but when I run it, the timer ticks but nothing happens. When investigating this I noticed that **the installer doesn't seem to have copied over a couple of dlls with it that are referenced in my app**. I can see them in my bin folder for the app, and I can see them listed in the `dependencies` array from the `Primary output from MyProject (Active)` node in my setup project. But they're not in the app's `Program Files` folder where the .exe is on the target machine.

Can anyone suggest some steps I can go through to ensure I'm doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to [explicitly add referenced files to the setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487905/setup-project-not-installing-referenced-project-content-files) (right-click on the setup project, and `Add` > `File...` and browse to/select the applicable files).

However, I'd still like to know:

- How this may be automated, particularly when packages are present in the app using NuGet
- Whether I missed a step that caused me to need to do it manually.
- Whether I may have missed something, for example relating to Install/Commit/Rollback/Uninstall custom actions that are required in the setup project